# how to convert a string to date format using dataweave

Tags: mule, date-conversion, dataweave

I am performing a CSV to CSV transformation using DataWeave.

One of the Input fields is a string `13/01/2015`. My requirement is to convert this string to a date format as `13-Jan-2015`.

I have tried using as `:string{"dd/MMM/yyyy}` and as `:date{format:dd/M/yyyy}` functions but did not succeed in changing the format.

Here is what I tried:

```
payload map { 
  "Order Number":$[0],
  "Order Date": ($[1] as :date{format:"d/M/yyyy"}),
}
```

This conversion gave the output as

```
Order Number,Order Date
14710655,2015-08-17
```

Then I tried the following:

```
 payload map {
    "Order Number":$[0],
    "Order Date": ($[1] as :date{format:"d/M/yyyy"}) as :string{format:"d/MMM/yyyy"})
 }
```

This conversion gave the output as

```
Order Number,Order Date
14710655,17/8/2015
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code.

Comment: added code to the question

Comment: Have you already looked at the [documentation](http://mulesoft.github.io/data-weave/#_changing_the_format_of_a_date)?

Comment: I just tried with the last alternative you mentioned and it gave `13/Jan/2015` as expected, what mule version are you using?

Comment: i have gone through the documentation @BurhanKhalid

Comment: i am using Anypoint Studio Version: 5.2.0 @Shoki

Answer (score 0):

When I tried :string { format: "dd-MMM-YYYY"}, it gave me 13-Jan-2015.

Comment: is your input a string? have you not used any :date{format:"dd-MMM-yyyy"} conversion?